# Concurrency issue with threads

Tags: java

I have a simple code, consisting of 4 threads (2 modify the data and 2 read the data). I just wrote this sample code to play around with Semaphor and I am not sure why I get ava.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification exception? Here are the source code and thanks for any insights.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class SemaphoreExample {
    public static class InnerWriterSemaphoreThread implements Runnable {

    private final List<String> fList;
    private final Semaphore fWriteSem;

    InnerWriterSemaphoreThread(List<String> list, Semaphore w) {
        fList = list;
        fWriteSem = w;
    }

    private void prune() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" in prune()..");
        for (String s : fList) {
            fList.remove(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        String text;
        while (true) {
            text = RandomTextGenerator.getRandomSNumbertring();
            try {
                while(!fWriteSem.tryAcquire()){
                    System.out.println(name+" waiting to accquire semaphore to write..");
                    Thread.sleep(0L,4);
                }
                if (fList.size() > 10) {
                    prune();
                }
                fList.add(text);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                fWriteSem.release();// notify readers that write has completed
                System.out.println(name+" finished writing, releasing semaphore..");
            }
        }//while()
    }//run()
    }//WriterSemaphoreThread
    public static class InnerReaderSemaphoreThread implements Runnable {

    private final List<String> fList;
    private final Semaphore fWriteSem;

    InnerReaderSemaphoreThread(List<String> list,Semaphore w) {
        fList = list;
        fWriteSem = w;
    }
    private void sleep(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(0L, 4);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(name + " in run()..");
            try {
                while(fList.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(name+" list is empty, going to sleep..");
                    sleep();
                }
                while(!fWriteSem.tryAcquire()){
                    System.out.println(name+" waiting to accquire semaphor to read..");
                    Thread.sleep(0l,4);
                }
                for (String text : fList) {
                    System.out.println(name + " reading from list " + text);
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                fWriteSem.release(); //Notify threads who want to write to the list
                System.out.println(name+" finished reading, releasing semaphore and going to sleep..");
                sleep();
            }
        }
    }
    }//ReaderSemaphoreThread

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Semaphore r = new Semaphore(1);
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new InnerWriterSemaphoreThread(list, r), "Thread 1");
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new InnerReaderSemaphoreThread(list, r), "Thread 2");
        Thread th3 = new Thread(new InnerWriterSemaphoreThread(list, r), "Thread 3");
        Thread th4 = new Thread(new InnerReaderSemaphoreThread(list, r), "Thread 4");
        th2.start();
        th4.start();
        th1.start();
        th3.start();
    }
}
```

Above is the sample source code

Comment: Click on the edit link below your question (above this comment) and add your code.

Comment: Hi, I edited the post, added the comment and when I tried to add the source code, it says you post has only code please add some comment. Back to square one :-)

Comment: You need to provide some example code *in addition* to the explanation of whats wrong.

Comment: Your exception could happen if you modify an ArrayList inside a for-each loop.

Comment: I have finally added a line of text at the end of the source code and it accepted. I hope the source code is clear to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @assylias mentioned in comment it happens when you remove elements from list in foreach loop. Just replace

```
for (String s : fList) {
   fList.remove(s);
}
```

with

```
fList.clear();
```

Comment: @assylias: Thank you for the insight. That's exactly where the exception is thrown when I look at the stack trace and I am completely puzzled for the past two days.  The dilemma for me remains as to why this exception is thrown? The shared Semaphore has only one permit, all threads wait to acquire the shared Semaphore before reading or modifying the list and only one thread succeeds hence only one thread is writing and pruning the list. I have a different version of the code using the ReadWriteLock, which works fine but my objective is to test the function of Semaphore per java documentation.

Comment: it is not a thread issue. You tried to remove items from list in loop. So such exception could be thrown if you call it in single thread app